# Azure App with Web API and Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I've Web App and API registered at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com. In my API, I've added in **Pre-authorized applications** my Web APP ID. So far so good. It works with the following scopes: `openid`, `profile`, and `api://APP_ID_GUID/access_as_user`.

I also need access to Microsoft Graph, but adding `https://graph.microsof.com/user.read` to my scopes results in:

> AADSTS700022: Provided value for the input parameter scope is not valid because it contains more than one resource. Scope `openid` `profile` `https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read` `api://APP_ID_GUID/access_as_user` is not valid.

How can I get token so I can use both? I need only to list the users in the Active Directory. The only way I see it is to get a separate access token for Microsoft Graph and use it when I want to query the users from AD.

Answer (score 3):

An access token is only valid on one API.
You need two access tokens to call two APIs.

As long as your app has been granted the necessary consent,
it can get the access tokens either by using a refresh token (you can get an access token for any resource using a refresh token) or a hidden iframe that uses implicit grant flow (that MSAL.JS uses).

Comment: You should also be able to get past the scope error itself by using `user.read` rather than `https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read`. When you use a fully qualified scope like that you are locking it to a single resource.

Comment: By the way Marc, if one wanted to ask for consent for multiple resources, would that be possible? I understand the error for token acquisition but for authentication and consent it should be possible to specify multiple resources :/ at least in the past it did not work.

Comment: I know you can do that with v1 tokens, I'm not sure about v2 however. I'll look into it and see if I can find a definitive answer. Maybe it's the case that you need to execute the _consent_ workflow separately first?

Comment: @juunas Requesting the `.default` permission for any of the resources that are part of the API permission (e.g. `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`) will trigger a consent prompt for *all* permissions and all resources statically defined for the app. If consent is granted, the resulting token will contain all the permissions for the resource you used in the request. Subsequent requests for other resources won't trigger consent anymore.

Comment: Right, so the correct approach for apps is to include all mandatory permissions statically and then use dynamic permissions only for enabling optional features.

Comment: I'm forced to use implicit grant flow. In order to get another token without making the user to log in again I should use MSAL.JS ?

Comment: MSAL.JS is the easiest way I think. It'll handle the hidden iframe stuff for you.